# Refresh CollectionViewSource (Entity Framework) bound control

Tags: .net, wpf, entity-framework, binding

I can't believe I can't find an answer to this...

1. I've created Entity Framework models generated from DB (SQL Server CE)
2. I dragged an Entity from Data Sources to my MainWindow, automagically creating this XAML:

   `<Window.Resources>
   <CollectionViewSource x:Key="contentItemsViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance my:ContentItem, CreateList=True}" />
   </Window.Resources>
   <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource contentItemsViewSource}">
   <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,22" Name="contentItemsDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" DataContext="{Binding}" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResizeRows="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}" Header="Id" Width="SizeToHeader" Visibility="Hidden" />
   <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="filePathColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=FilePath}" Header="File Path" Width="SizeToCells" />
   <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="fileSizeColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=FileSize}" Header="File Size" Width="SizeToHeader" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
   </Grid>`

(excuse the XML formatting, the code button doesn't seem to work with it).

I'm loading data in with this code:

```
foreach (String file in files.FileNames)
{
  ContentItem c = new ContentItem() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), FilePath = file, FileSize = (Int32)finfo.Length };
  db.AddToContentItems(c);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

This all works, except I need to update the datagrid. The only way I can find to do this is re-using some automagic code created when I bound the entity to the datagrid:

```
System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource contentItemsViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("contentItemsViewSource")));
System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<SwordfishWPF.ContentItem> contentItemsQuery = this.GetContentItemsQuery(db);
contentItemsViewSource.Source = contentItemsQuery.Execute(System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.AppendOnly);
```

Surely there's a simpler way? `datagrid.Items.Refresh()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(datagrid.ItemsSource).Refresh();
```